# Truth table to bitwise expression

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

Given a truth table with input bits and output bits, it is easy to find the boolean expression combining the input bits into a single output bit?

My problem is, that the derived boolean expression operates on each bit individually.

I am looking for the same procedure but using bitwise operators used in programming languages, which operate on all input bits in parallel to derive the output bits in parallel.

Example problem:

- input: 8-bit integer of which only some input bits are relevant, say bit 2 & 5. The state of the others is irrelevant to the output.
- output: 8-bit integer with two relevant output bits that depend on the state of the two relevant input bits, say bits 3 & 6. All other bits should be set uniformly to either 1 or 0.

Is there a way to:

1. Derive a formula/algorithm with bitwise operations operating on the input integer to replicate the "partial truth table"?
2. Minimize the complexity of the derived formula/algorithm?

Comment: a table of 256 elements (8 bits) should do you fine

Comment: @BeyelerStudios You are referring to a lookup table. I am looking for a bitwise expression. The lookup table is reasonable for small inputs but too expensive for large inputs (of which only some are used). For 2 output bits and 32 input bits it would require 2*2^31/8/1024/1024 megabytes = 512 megabytes!

Comment: To quote: *input: [...] integer of which **only some input bits are relevant**, [...] The state of the others is irrelevant*: so compress your input down to the relevant bits first and use those for the lookup. As long as no more than `k` bits are important, it doesn't matter how many input bits you get, the lookup table will contain `2^k` elements. If you get 32 significant and independent (orthagonal) input bits (i.e. no lossless compression possible), you'll get as complex a binary expression as you would get a large lookup table.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios you can minimize binary expression later. You can optimize look up table as well, like somehow store only those input vectors which output True or False (with primitive hashtable for example).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would do something like this:

First define some bit mask:

```
#define BITMASK0 (1<<0)
#define BITMASK1 (1<<1)
#define BITMASK2 (1<<2)
#define BITMASK3 (1<<3)
#define BITMASK4 (1<<4)
```

then, I would define how to isolate the input bits:

```
#define INBIT0(x) (BITMASK0&(x))>>0
#define INBIT1(x) (BITMASK1&(x))>>1
#define INBIT2(x) (BITMASK2&(x))>>2
#define INBIT3(x) (BITMASK3&(x))>>3
#define INBIT4(x) (BITMASK4&(x))>>4
```

and how to put the output bits in the correct output position

```
#define OUTBIT0(x) ((x)<<0) & BITMASK0
#define OUTBIT1(x) ((x)<<1) & BITMASK1
#define OUTBIT2(x) ((x)<<2) & BITMASK2
#define OUTBIT3(x) ((x)<<3) & BITMASK3
#define OUTBIT4(x) ((x)<<4) & BITMASK4
```

now, in code, I would describe how to manipulate it, according to your logic

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char a; // choose your initialization here
    unsigned char b = 0;

    b = OUTBIT0(1) | OUTBIT1(INBIT5(a) & INBIT3(a)) | OUTBIT2(0);
}
```

Comment: How does this answer either of the 2 questions?

Comment: Thanks. This answers my first question: how to transform a truth table to a bitwise expression. In theory it should now be possible to algebraically simplify this bitwise expression. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Andrey As ARF said, I think it answers the first question, how to decompose a input integer to mimic a truth table.

Comment: @ARF I think you could minimize the expression using what Andrey has suggested as, for example, Karnaugh map that is related directly to circuit minimization

Comment: @Amadeus ok then if that is what OP meant, I understood the question is  how to generate the expressions from truth table not how to write them in C nicely.

Comment: @Andrey I understood that he/she already have an expression, or a partial expression, that is coded in a c/c++ type and how to express it to generate an output also coded in a c/c++ type.

Comment: @Amadeus Re Karnaugh map: That only minimizes boolean expressions, right? Not the bitwise expression `b = OUTBIT0(1) | OUTBIT1(INBIT5(a) & INBIT3(a)) | OUTBIT2(0);`. According to Andrey's comment to his answer that is a problem that is next to impossible.

Comment: @ARF bitwise operations operates bit by bit. This means that an output bit c_i is changed by its operands bits a_i and b_i. There is no way to make an output bit c_i being changed by operands a_x and b_y directly. So, no, I can't see how to optimize an output expression with diferents input bits using bitwise expression.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how and what you want to achieve practically.

1. Derive a formula/algorithm with bitwise operations operating on the input integer to replicate the "partial truth table"?

There is really simple and suboptimal way to solve it: [Canonical Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form). Basically it is combinations of basic operators (and, or, not) for every True or False outputs. Why is it suboptimal? Because if you have 4 input bits and 1 output bit and 50% of outputs are True, the resultant expression will contain around 43 operators. If you don't plan to do extreme loads of operations it is OK practically, any modern CPU can execute millions of such expressions per second. If you have a significantly skewed ratio of either outputs this can be quite effective.

2. Minimize the complexity of the derived formula/algorithm?

This is non-trivial part and there are certain approaches. It is called  [circuit minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions). If you just have a function that you need to optimize you can use [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), it is designed to be used by humans. If you need to automate it look into [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) or [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer).

**Edit:** One thing to note, there are no guarantees that your function can actually be reduced to a compact expression.

Comment: You are speaking of boolean operations here, right? They operate on one or two input bits to create a single output bit. I am looking for an algorithm using bitwise operations that operate on all x input bits creating all y output bits.

Comment: @ARF All those bitwise operators can be decomposed into boolean operators. This distinction is purely matter of syntax. Let's say you have shift operator << and let's say your inputs are 2 bits. You have (2 x 2) -> 5 function. Which can be decomposed into 5 boolean functions.

Comment: I understand that but I am still looking for a bitwise expression not a boolean expression. Their compiled assembly of the bitwise expression should be much more compact for all but trivial expressions.

Comment: @ARF you never mentioned what are your final goals and actual requirements so it is hard to give practical advice, but it seems for me that you want too much at the same time. Optimizing 1-bit output function is already nontrivial task, optimizing multibit output functio (bitwise) is some completely different level. More of it - it is generally unsolvable. It can easily require operators that are non existent. Very simple example - bit count.